# Memory leak due to static reference to inner class in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, memory-leaks, static

There is problem of memory leak caused by `mInnerClassFragment`:

```
public class someActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    void memFuncOfMain() {
        InnerClassFragment mFrag = InnerClassFragment.mInnerClassFragment;
        mFrag.var1 = true;
        mFrag.getContext();
    }

    public static class InnerClassFragment extends Fragment{
        private static InnerClassFragment mInnerClassFragment;

        private boolean var1 = false;

        public InnerClassFragment(){
            mInnerClassFragment = this;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I correct this? According to my understanding, outer class has static ref to inner class which caused the problem. mInnerClassFragment must not be static. But how do I remove the dependency in outer class: `InnerClassFragment mFrag = InnerClassFragment.mInnerClassFragment;` ?

Comment: Can you clairfy, what you mean by memory leak? What is the behaviour you are seeing and trying to avoid? In general making inner classes static is the correct choice here to avoid memory leaks, as a non-static class contains a `this` reference to the outer class instance.

Comment: inner class should be static, but the ref, mInnerClassFragment should not be. Problem is that the memory referenced by mInnerClassFragment is not being released.

Comment: So what prevents you from making it not static?

Comment: ```InnerClassFragment mFrag = InnerClassFragment.mInnerClassFragment;```
this

Comment: I'm asking, because you can just remove this property entirely and use the constructor of the inner class in the line you mentioned.

Comment: you mean this:
```InnerClassFragment mFrag = new InnerClassFragment();```

Problem with this is, it will create a new instance of InnerClassFragment class, and then when we write ```mFrag.getContext()``` , we will get context of this newly created Fragment. 
We need context of current fragment

Comment: a) When you request a Fragment's Context it will probably cause headaches if you depend on it being a very specific Context. Most likely you would get a reference to you Activity instance there anyway.

b.) You could always save your Fragment instance in a property of the surrounding class insted of using a static variable. This way the lifetime of the instance of the inner class is limited to the lifetime of the outer class instance.

Comment: Its not just about the Context, we cannot create a new fragment each time in this case. We want to use the current fragment only. But, I understood your point, maybe we can use findFragmentByTag in the Activity, see if it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: This creates a memory leak, but not anything horrible. It will leak at most one instance of `InnerClassFragment` whose reference is stored in the variable `mInnerClassFragment`. I don't think I would worry about it. It isn't like a true memory leak in that the leaked memory will grow and grow over time until your app crashes.

Comment: Understood, but this argument won't fly during code review. XD